# How can I plot a function (unidimensional) in a 3D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, parametric-functions

I would like to plot a figure like that using Mathematica.
They figure are three plane wave ( cosine or sin ) all share and have the same coordinate origin. As you observe, the waves propagate along the XZ plane.

[image: Plot]

I tried to do it as  in the following

f[n_, x_] := Sin[x (2.1  n)];

ParametricPlot3D[ Evaluate[Table[{x, n, f[n, x]}, {n, 3}]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 1}]

and using

ParametricPlot3D[{{Sin[2 x], 1, x}, {Sin[2.1  x ], 1, x}, {Sin[2.2  x], 1, x}}, {x, 0, 10}]

Unfortunately, the plots are so far to be similar and nice. 
Please, any comment will be welcome and thanks in advance.

Comment: `Unfortunately, the plots are so far to be similar and nice.` I don't get it. What is the problem?

Comment: Thank for your reply: The question is how to obtain a figure similar as the book?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate[Table[{x Cos[θ], x Sin[θ], Sin[2 x]}, 
 {θ, 0, Pi/2, Pi/6}]], {x, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: It works. However,  I need to plot only three curves. 
What do I have to change in your code? 

  ParametricPlot3D[  Evaluate[Table[{x Cos[\[Theta]], x Sin[\[Theta]], 
    Sin[2 x]}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi/2, Pi/2}]], {x, 0, 10}]

Answer (score 0):

I solve using the following code

`waves = ParametricPlot3D[{{t x, Sin[t x], 0}, {0 , Sin[t x], t x }, {t x , Sin[t x], t x }}, {t, 0, Pi}, {x, 0, 4}]`

However, I can not use ViewPoint to show the plot in the usual 3D form.